# Anyone ported Snoop Component Suite version 3.0 to Delphi 2010 ? (ie. Unicode issues)

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010, winpcap

Has anyone ported "Snoop Component Suite version 3.0" by http://www.netlab.co.kr

To Delphi 2010 ?

Its a great WinPCap library. Just doesn't work on Delphi 2010 (unicode)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the Snoop components suite at this link.  Just a couple of links to other pages.

You could try the [free components from Magenta Systems](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp).  The web site says it's compatible with Delphi 6 - 2010.